# Query function in Google Sheets gives no result when comparing numbers, but data is present in the dataset

Tags: google-sheets

I am comparing a text from sheet a (All Blank Options sheet, Cell E) with the data set (Base Substitution sheet, Cells A and B).

I want to return column D of the data set where Cell E in blank options is in between values in Cells A and B

This keeps giving me no results.

I'm using the following query:

**=query(Bs,"Select D where C='"&B6185&"' and A<='"&E6185&"'" and B>= '"&E6185&"')**

[You can refer to the sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vEDyWkSUvn0lEsuIUNe24nmKgFVmOVUNFZgFe39RZ4A/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not quote a number

```
=query(Bs,"Select D where C='"&B6185&"' and A<="&E6185&" and B>="&E6185)
```